# How Do I Send a Dictionary to a Client using Vapor Websockets

Tags: json, swift, websocket, vapor

I've [continued this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004678/receiving-websocket-data-in-swift), because the focus has changed, but is related.

Vapor is communicating between a server and and iOS client. Just setup code, for learning purposes.

Now, I want to send a dictionary of values via the established connection using JSON. I'm getting caught up in the unexplained logic of demo code, but here's where I am, in my vapor routes:

```
    app.webSocket("respond") { req, ws in
        ws.onText { ws, text in
            print(text)
        
            let msgDict = "{'name' = 'bobby'}"
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            let data = try encoder.encode(msgDict)
                
            ws.send(data)
        }
    }
```

This won't compile:  `Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(WebSocket, String) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(WebSocket, String) -> ()'`

while I generally understand this error, and dependent on how I play with this it varies.

What generally I'm looking for is a simple pattern to take internal dictionary values, encode them into JSON, and send them. What am I not doing, or not doing right?

Answer (score 4):

I see two problems with that code.

The first one, explained by the compiling error, it's actually telling that it will not handle any errors thrown. When you do `encoder.encode(msgDict)`, this code can throw an `Error`, and you're not handling this possible error anywhere. If you handle that possible error, code you wrote in that closure will have the expected type. You have a few options to do so:

- Wrap the code around a `do-catch` block

```swift
do {
    let data = try encoder.encode(msgDict)
    ws.send(data)
} catch let error {
    // Handle error
}
```

- Use `try?`, means you do not handle the error but get `nil` as a result, if an error occurred.

```swift
if let data = try? encoder.encode(msgDict) {
    ws.send(data)
}
```

- Use `try!`, means you force-unwrap the result (not advisable, but you can try, if you're 100% sure)

```swift
let data = try! encoder.encode(msgDict)
ws.send(data)
```

The second problem is how you're writing that response - `"{'name' = 'bobby'}"`. This is an invalid JSON, you should use double quotes instead:

```swift
let msgDict = "{\"name\" = \"bobby\"}"
```

You can also use `Dictionary`, as long as the content is of type `Encodable`:

```swift
let msgDict = ["name": "bobby"]
```

You can also use `JSONEncoder` to encode any instances of classes that conform to `Encodable`.

So the whole thing, I'd write like this:

```swift
app.webSocket("respond") { req, ws in
    ws.onText { ws, text in
        print(text)
    
        let msgDict = ["name": "bobby"]
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(msgDict)
            ws.send(data)
        }
        catch let error {
            print("An error occurred: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good – thanks. The errors are cleared up, although it complains about the error itself. What I'm down to now is a very Vapor-specific error, which is that I'm not dealing with the future/promise structure in ws.send(). I think I know where to look to figure that out....

Comment: @DanDonaldson I updated my answer, there was something I wrote wrong while catching the error and I corrected it.

Comment: @DanDonaldson If this solved your original question, I'd if appreciate if you marked it as an answer.

Comment: sure @Jobert. I'm not sure where you live, but I'm in SE Asia. Your answer came in at the end of my working day, now I'm starting a new one. Try to remember the world is bigger than your backyard   :)  I've marked it, but I'm treating it as not fully proved. I'm having to move to other issues before I can return to this one.

Comment: @DanDonaldson I just felt like I engaged and put some effort on this one and needed some feedback (some times you don't get that around here and it's very demotivating). Thank you for responding and I wish you good luck with your work! :)

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that a `do - catch` block is missing

```
do {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let data = try encoder.encode(msgDict)
    ws.send(data)
} catch { print(error) }
```

However your approach to create JSON cannot work because `msgDict` is neither valid JSON nor a Swift dictionary.

To encode the dictionary with `JSONEncoder` it must be a Swift dictionary

```
let msgDict = ["name":"bobby"]
```

But `JSONEncoder` is overkill. A simpler way is to create the JSON dictionary literally

```
app.webSocket("respond") { req, ws in
    ws.onText { ws, text in
        print(text)
    
        let msgDict = #"{"name":"bobby"}"#
        ws.send(Data(msgDict.utf8))
    }
}
```